# Code has no error and logcat has nothing, but still unfortunately app stopped error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
package com.example.darshreddy.diser;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SQLite extends Activity {
    Button but;
    EditText nam, mail, pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        nam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passw);
        mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emi);
        but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        but.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    }
        public void onClick(View arg0){
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.button2:
                boolean didItwork=true;
                try {
                    String name = nam.getText().toString();
                    String passw = pass.getText().toString();
                    String eml = mail.getText().toString();

                    SQL entry = new SQL(SQLite.this);
                    entry.open();
                    entry.createEntry(name, passw, eml);
                    entry.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    didItwork=false;
                }finally {
                    if (didItwork) {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Heck yea!!");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setText("success");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    }

                }
        break;}
    }
}
```

This is the code I wrote for executing `SQLite` database related file. I had
linked a registration from with it and the error is "unfortunately the app has stopped". please help me find the error if any. or suggest me some changes.
**logcat shows**

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.darshreddy.diser/com.example.darshreddy.diser.SQLite}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.darshreddy.diser.SQLite cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener"

Comment: you are catching your exceptions but not printing the stacktrace. that's why there is nothing in logcat.

Comment: print your exception using stacktrace

Comment: How do I do that?
sorry I'm a beginner!

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();  didItwork=false; }`

Comment: setting-->go to build,execution,deployment
inside than debugger-> compiler
add command -line option --stacktrace or -debug
and then clean project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `OnClickListener` interface like:

```
public class SQLite extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Also, add `e.printStackTrace()` in `catch block` as suggested by @Brett Jeffreson to get error/crash trace in log

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, as it is related to database, I would suggest to ask a new question

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what error/problem are you getting?